# Выпадающее меню в ie9

Tags: jquery, javascript

помогите пожалуйста исправить [выпадающее меню](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/q2/)

проблема в том, что оно не работает в ie9. скрипт простейший

```
$(".nav_slide").on('click', function(event){
    var t = event.target || event.srcElement

    if(t.className !=  'link_slide'){
        $("#nav_slide_content").slideToggle("slow");

        $('#nav_slide_toggle').toggleClass("active"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291331/id-classname-jquery-not-working-in-ie9

используйте 

    $(t).hasClass('link_slide');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле, ваша проблема решается достаточно просто - подключите версию библиотеки старее, чем 2.* (например, версию 1.9.1.). Дело в том, что из этой версии была удалена поддержка ослов ниже 10-ого.

P.S. В дополнение к комментарию [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto): для доступа к свойствам/атрибутам элемента, достаточно использовать **$(this)** и не обязательно использовать триггер:

```
$(".nav_slide").on('click', function(event){

    if(!$(this).hasClass('link_slide')){
        $("#nav_slide_content").slideToggle("slow");
        $('#nav_slide_toggle').toggleClass("active"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: [ниже 9го...](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

[и тут ещё](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

> As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers.